# S3 Buckets disappeared. "No bucket of that name" when accessing via known link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I access my S3 account I either get the "Start Screen" with instructions how to set up a bucket, or a blank S3 screen.

I have tried using a link to a file to see whether the file is actually there but I get a "No bucket of that name" message.

Most of these files (hundreds of them) have been up or 3-4 years and I have never had a problem.

The only access (other than to retrieve a link) over the past few years is to change my email address and password (approx 1-2 weeks ago) and I uploaded a few files over the last few days.

I am not technical at all but am rather anxious as I have a lot of angry customers wanting links that I cannot provide. I do have all of the files on my computer, however, they are all way too big to email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am also happy to pay someone to fix this for me if that is possible.

Thanks

Comment: *"No bucket of that name"*...? Or do You see this: `<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
    <Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
    ...
    </Error>` with the expected bucket name mentioned in the error?

Comment: Are you accessing the correct region containing your data? There is an option in the top right corner with region selection. Check if it contains "Global" or some region name.

Comment: ask @Smajl pointed out, you are probably in the wrong region.

Comment: @Mircea the S3 console unlike other services does not require region selection.  All buckets in all regions are displayed (all regions know of the existence, and region, of all buckets).  Requesting an object from the wrong region (e.g. `http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example-bucket-in-another-region`) will return an error "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

Comment: What tool (software) are you using to access S3 that is showing a start screen?

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your responses.  The message I am getting is: <Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message><BucketName>rmd</BucketName><RequestId>53ADD9B586862B39</RequestId>                                      <HostId>BOUtrcmDltOfDv2BDLZPJNt9w9ZU+fyLJEXprPVDmHModiJ5ggtJ0IG1k7Jgk34SInEF6JXFxpc=</HostId></Error>                                          Yes, the Global drop down says that I do not need to select a region.                 I have tried accessing directly, via Cloudberry and via S3.

Comment: Also, I contacted Amazon and got the response:   I have heard back from the Service team and they have informed me that they are unable to perform forensics on your account. If you believe someone may have maliciously or accidentally deleted your buckets, please Rotate your keys and turn on bucket logging to see if there are attempts to access the bucket using the old key is still being accessed going forward.  What do they mean - cannot perform forensics?  How can all of my data disappear?  What should I do?

Comment: @DiamondJ I know this is an old post but I have the same problem. The images are just gone suddenly. I didn't use any script or called anything.